# ckeditor 5 converting image in base64

Tags: reactjs, base64, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am currently using ckeditor '6.1.0'. If I upload an image, it gets converted to base64 format.

Base64 images are too large, so I don't want it. Is there any way so my images don't get changed in Base64 instead they appear as normal image URLs? as i am sending ckeditor data in API payload and the payload have a limit of 400kb which is my i am getting this issue as a single base 64 image can be of a loat of MB